# save fragment state in a bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity, which basically is a navigation bottom bar containing fragments. If the the user is logged in, the bottom navigation shows 4 fragments: market, favorite, upload and profile. If the user is a guest, there are two fragments: market and login.

Before, every time someone swapped from a fragment to another, it was generated again. However, I wanted to conserve the state of the fragment, so if someone applied a filter in the market and came back, it had to keep the filter applied. I tried implementing this solution https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711 but I feel is not the best so far.

The code of the nav activity is:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Fragment market= new MarketFragment();
    final Fragment favorite = new FavoriteFragment();
    final Fragment updateProduct = new AddProductFragment();
    final Fragment userProfile = new UserProfileFragment();
    final Fragment loginregister = new LoginOrRegisterFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = market;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(UnipopApp.usuariLoggejat.getUserLogged() != null){
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        else{
            setContentView(R.layout.main_guest);
        }
        setUpNavigation();
    }

    public void setUpNavigation() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
        if(UnipopApp.usuariLoggejat.getUserLogged() != null) {
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavegationItemSelectedListener);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, favorite, "2").hide(favorite).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, updateProduct, "3").hide(updateProduct).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, userProfile, "5").hide(userProfile).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, market, "1").commit();
        }
        else {
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_guest);
            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavegationItemSelectedListener);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_guest, loginregister, "6").hide(loginregister).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_guest, market, "1").commit();
        }
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavegationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(market).commit();
                    active = market;
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_favorites:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(favorite).commit();
                    active = favorite;
                    return true;
                case R.id.addProduct_fragment:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(updateProduct).commit();
                    active = updateProduct;
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_user_profile:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(userProfile).commit();
                    active = userProfile;
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_user_profile_guest:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(loginregister).commit();
                    active = loginregister;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

It works but I had to delete the nav graph... However, the thing is that when someone marks a product as favorite in the market and moves to the favorite fragment, it does not appear. Obviously, it just shows up the fragment again, it does not generate it back with the call from the server.

I am looking for other options because I don't like this solution. If someone can lend me a hand, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The solution you are using is very memory consuming and is not scalable.
I hope you have to use a shareviewmodel and save your state to it. 
You should use a combination of fragments onSavedInstance() and shared viewmodel. 

When you switch back to the fragment in bottomnavigation bar, the viewmodel will pass back the non config data like last filtered list of results. Also you may have to do minor UI updates like showing filter count, smooth scrolling to the last scrolled position by retrieving these state data from savedinstance

Comment: Do you have any code of example for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Recommended solution using Bottom Navigation View and Fragment Navigation. Use [Activity's SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) to persist the states of all the navigation fragments.

**Layout XML** (rees/layout/activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/core_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Navigation XML** (res/navigation/core_navigation.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_feed">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.example.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/home_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
    android:name="com.example.FavoritesFragment"
    android:label="@string/favorites_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/favorites_fragment" />

<!--Fill this with other fragments like above-->

</navigation>
```

**Menu XML** (res/menu/bottom_navigation_menu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/home_title"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorites"
    android:title="@string/favorites_title"/>

<!--Fill this with other fragments like above-->

</menu>
```

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupNavigation()
    }

    private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I had before but if you swap from a fragment to another, imagine you are in the RV of products, in the product 60, I want the user to keep seeing the product 60 when he comes back to the fragment.

Comment: @LauraGalera You can keep track of the scroll XY coordinate in your view model through recycler view listeners so that you can set it back again whenever the user returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can save filter selection in fragment's viewmodel.